# find the minimum value of $a+b+c$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, natural-numbers

There are natural numbers: $a$, $b$, $c$.

$$\begin{cases}
ab+bc+ca+\frac32(a+b+c)=5015,\\
2abc-a-b-c=6366
\end{cases}
$$

I need to find the minimum value of $a+b+c$.
To my mind there's something connected with the derivative. I've already tried to find an equation for $a+b+c$, but I stuck right here.
If we do some math in the second equation, we can get this one

$a+b+c=3183/abc$
Everything's great, but if we consider $a+b+c = l$ (for example), then we need to find a minimum of this function. But as far as I'm concerned this is a Hyperbolic function, which doesn't have extreme values. So there's my first confusion.

Moving on I decided to do something with a first equation. But, unfortunately, no matter how I rearrange my $a$, $b$ and $c$ I get some equations and can't get anything useful out of it.

And the last thing. If I get an equation for $a+b+c$ from the first equation then find a derivative and its zero value, I get $c = -b$.

Well, that perfectly concludes the problem. Could anyone help me get this one done?

Sorry for image confusion.

Comment: The first equation in the system needs some check. Please do verify it.

Comment: It's right. Checked it a dozen times

Comment: The second equation, when dividing both sides with 5, gives that $a+b+c=1003$ so $a+b+c$ is constant. Your problem is malformed, or very strange.

Comment: I'm sorry, but maybe you're speaking abot the first one?

Comment: And still I do not understand your approach..

Comment: Oops, now I realize what you're talking about. It's just mathematics engine converting my image. Sorry for that

Comment: I strongly suggest that we keep the picture, since it is not clear what the equations mean; at least until OP clarifies what he meant. @user1131662: It this two or three equations? Perhaps it would be better to write $\frac32$ instead of $1,5$; since various countries use various symbols for decimal separators and this might be confusing.

Comment: I'm really sorry for that confusion, but now it seems to be fixed.

Comment: @user1131662 To be sure - the formulas I've edited into your post now are what you intended?

Comment: Yes, perfectly right, thank you very much, my editing skills are far way below that convertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the half the 2. equation to the 1. equation you get:
$$
abc+(ab+bc+ca)+(a+b+c)=8198,
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)  =8198+1=3\cdot 3 \cdot 911.
$$
So $a=2,b=2$ and $c=910$.

Comment: Wow, couldn't imagine it to be so simle as that. Nevertheless thank you for your spent time, it's really wonderful. And without derivatives. Again.

Comment: your welcome, I'm glad if could help

Answer (score 2):

Hint: [Lagrange multipliers](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/lagrange-multiplier.pdf).

I mean, you've to find the minimum of the function

$$
f(a,b,c) = a + b + c \ ,
$$

subject to the restrictions $g_1(a,b,c) = 0$ and $g_2(a,b,c) = 0$, where

$$
g_1(a,b,c) = ab + bc + ca + \frac{3}{2}(a+b+c) - 5016 \qquad \text{and} \qquad g_2(a,b,c) = 2abc - a - b -c - 6366 \ .
$$

So, you look for the zeros of the equation

$$
\nabla f(a,b,c) - \lambda_1 \nabla g_1(a,b,c) - \lambda_2 \nabla g_2(a,b,c) = 0 \ ,
$$

subject to the restrictions $g_1 = 0$ and $ g_2 = 0$.

Once you have those zeros $(a,b,c)$ together with its multipliers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, you have to check whether the Hessian at these points is a positive definite matrix or not:

$$
Hf(a,b,c) - \lambda_1 Hg_1 (a,b,c)- \lambda_2 Hg_2 (a,b,c) \ .
$$

Comment: Thanks, that needs a bit of studying, hopefully tomorrow I'll finish this thing.